# Does every Perl module in a distribution need to have a version number?

Tags: perl, cpan, perl-module

I'm maintaining a CPAN distribution that has over 100 .pm files.  Do each of them need to have a $VERSION, or is it okay to just include it in the main module?

For the other modules in the distribution, what effect does including or not including the $VERSION have?

In case it's relevant to the question, people should only be "use"-ing the main module in this distribution.  And, for the purpose of this question, I'm not asking about *how* it should be specified in any file, just *whether* or not it's present in any form.

Comment: Empirically, lots of modules don't put the version number in every `.pm` file. If you do a snapshot bundle (`b` in `cpanp`), you'll see that. Personally, I don't like that (so all the `.pm` files in my module are version stamped with the same version), but there are lots of modules (people) that do it otherwise. And the worst problems come when a module is updated but some bit isn't, so CPANPLUS thinks the module is out of date even though installing the latest version doesn't change anything. I've got 5 modules like that at the moment, and I'm sorely tempted to delete them all!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That looks like an answer to me, would you mind posting it as one?

Comment: Need, no.  Is it a good thing and trivial and hence not worth *not* doing?  Yes.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: your wish is my command.

Answer (score 11):

Empirically, lots of modules don't put the version number in every `.pm` file. If you do a snapshot bundle (`b` in `cpanp`) and look at the generated file, you'll see that.  On my machine, the snapshot for Perl 5.16.2 with *lots* of modules added contained 7962 modules, but 2070 of those included 'undef' as the version (so roughly 1 in 4 has undef as the version).

Personally, I don't like that, so all the `.pm` files in my module — [DBD::Informix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3A%3AInformix) — are version stamped with the same version in each release (the current release is 2013.0118, and all the `.pm` files are stamped with 2013.0118 as the version number), but there are lots of modules (people) that do it otherwise.

- You do not have to provide a version number for every `.pm` file.
- On the whole, it is better if you do in fact provide a version number for every `.pm` file.
- I think it is sensible to provide the same version number for all `.pm` files in a distribution.

In my view, the worst problems come when a module is updated but some bit isn't, so CPANPLUS thinks the module is out of date even though installing the latest version doesn't change anything. I've got 5 modules like that at the moment, and I'm sorely tempted to delete them all, especially since I'm not really using them.  (Sometimes, that's triggered by a file being installed in a new location, but I don't think that's the only cause. I'm not sure what else triggers it, but it is a problem that occurs periodically.)